# Silk Browser only deletes highlighted text partially on address bar

Tags: browser

I'm using Silk Browser on Amazon Fire 10 tablet. When I highlight an entry in the address bar to delete it using the backspace/delete button, it highlights it, but only deletes some of it.

Ex. `https://superuser.com/` is highlighted. When I hit backspace, `user.com` is left in the address bar.

I'm clueless.